# How do I detect whether stderr is connected to a terminal from within a script?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to experiment with terminals and colored output, but at the same time I want to make stdout/stderr redirection to file possible without having to deal with these escape sequences.

Is there any way to check whether `stderr` is connected to a terminal from within a shell script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The file descriptor for standard error, stderr, is 2.  The [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) or `[` command (which is often a shell built-in) has an option, `-t`, to test whether a file descriptor is connected to a terminal:

```
if [ -t 2 ]
then : stderr is a terminal
else : stderr is not a terminal
fi
```